# Cannot find namespace 'go'

Tags: javascript, typescript, user-interface, angular8, gojs

I am integrating gojs in angular 8 project.

I have already installed gojs-angular package.

npm install gojs gojs-angular.

Below is the code snippet.

error: Cannot find namespace 'go'

**public initDiagram(): go.Diagram {};**

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to restart nodemon?

Comment: I have restarted but still the error is coming.

error TS2686: 'go' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead. 

const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

Comment: I have tried to add script in index.html file but still getting the error.

    <script src="assets/release/go.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Please follow and verify below steps.

1. Install gojs and gojs-angular

npm i gojs gojs-angular

2. import * as go from 'gojs';

We can just use variable by import in the component.ts file.

No need to add script or import in other places,